# PHP str_replace replace space with dash, but too many dash

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have this string here `photo of the day - 2011` and I need to look like `photo-of-the-day-2011` when I do a str_replace, I get this output:

`photo-of-the-day---2011` what can I do to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
$albumName = 'photo of the day - 2011'; (this comes from a db and cannot change it)
$albumName = str_replace(" ", "-", $albumName);
```

Comment: You should mark Jon's answer as correct to help others.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the more powerful [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), instructing it to replace runs of dashes and/or spaces with a single dash:

```
$name = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $name);
```

`[\s-]+` is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) that matches "one or more of: whitespace and dashes".